# UIBarButtonItem Cancel does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uibarbuttonitem, cancel-button

I want to cancel the second view controller with a `UIBarButtonItem`, but I just don't get the code right. Please help.

Viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]]) {
        SecondViewController *vc2 = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc2.delegate = self;
    }
}

-(void)dismissViewController
{
    NSLog(@"dismissed");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Secondviewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) dismissViewController;

@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)backBarButtonItemPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
@end
```

BackbarButton means cancelbutton

Secondviewcontroller.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)backBarButtonItemPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.delegate dismissViewController];
}
@end
```

Comment: Why is your `dismissViewController` implemented in in your first ViewController when it is declared in your `SecondViewController.h`?

Comment: To dismiss from first VC and call in second VC

Comment: But why do you have a declaration for it in your second view controller if you don't use it. Anyways if this button isn't going to save any data and you just want to exit, try to ctrl + drag from the button to the `Exit` outlet on the Storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dismiss in `secondViewController`,I do not see the meaning of Delegate in your code

```
- (IBAction)backBarButtonItemPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}
```

If you use show segue,and you have a navigationController with these two ViewControllers,Use

```
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender {
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
}
```

Comment: Ty for answering, that doenst work, its still not dismissing. i tried delegate to dismiss from first VC.

Comment: What type of segue are you using?

Comment: I used show segue from a UIBarButtonItem in First VC to Second VC all done in storyboard

Comment: If you have a navigationController with them,use `popViewControllerAnimated`,See What I update